# Replacing Value of Empty Node in SQL XML

Tags: sql-server, xml

I've come across a problem with modifying XML within SQL Server that doesn't seem to make sense to me. I want to update the value of an empty node, but it doesn't seem to be working. For instance, say I have this XML tree:

```
<root>
    <node />
</root>
```

and I want to update the value of `<node />` with 'foo' so I have the XML query:

```
UPDATE  [Table]
SET     [XmlColumn].modify('
        replace value of (root/node/text())[1]
        with "foo"')
```

For some reason, this doesn't work. It treats the node like it doesn't exist. If the node already has a value (e.g., `<node>bar</node>`), it works just fine, but when the node is empty, it silently ignores the command, without even throwing any errors. Is there a way to make SQL Server acknowledge a `replace value of` on an empty node?

**EDIT:**

I want the end result of this query to be this:

```
<root>
    <node>
        foo
    </node>
</root>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Update XML field with no text in T-SQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6254630/update-xml-field-with-no-text-in-t-sql)

Comment: Awesome, Mikael. This solution seems way cleaner than the one pointed to by Andrey. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Will this be of any help: http://whyiamright.wordpress.com/2008/01/02/updating-xml-column-in-sql-server-2005/?

You seem to miss slash in the begining of xpath.

**EDIT**: Then it seems to be a duplicate of this question:

[Update Empty XML Tag in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2812036/update-empty-xml-tag-in-sql-server)

Comment: The leading slash only makes the path absolute. Without it, the XPath will match any node whose path ends with `root/node`. Since there aren't any other nodes in the tree, in this instance, the leading slash makes no difference.

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2812036/update-empty-xml-tag-in-sql-server

Comment: not sure why this is the accepted answer; as @Chris mentioned above, the leading slash makes no difference in this scenario

Answer (score 8):

```
UPDATE  [Table] 
SET     [XmlColumn].modify(' insert text{"foo"} into (/root/node)[1]')
```

Try out this work for me

Comment: What about if instead of `"foo"` I want a variable? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32253235/how-to-use-if-else-statement-to-update-or-create-new-xml-node-entry-in-sql

Comment: In this case you can use:
```' insert text{sql:variable("@variableName")} into (/root/node)[1]'```

Comment: This should be marked as the answer.  I had the same issue as the OP and my addressing was fine (no missing slashes, etc.) -- this is what actually worked for an empty node; 'replace value' did NOT.  Thank you @jaspreet !

Answer (score 0):

Necromancing. 
Providing an actual answer:

You cannot do this in one pass. 
You first need to set the value to empty (replace if it exists), and then insert it:

```
SET @tXML.modify('replace value of (//path[contains("0000X1,0000X2", @data-objid) and string-length(@data-objid) != 0]/text())[1] with ""')
SET @tXML.modify('insert text{"This Works"} into (//path[contains("0000X1,0000X2", @data-objid) and string-length(@data-objid) != 0])[1]')
```

example XML used:

```
DECLARE @tXML xml = '<svg>
<g>
<path></path>
<path data-objid="0000X1">tt</path>
<path data-objid="0000X2"></path>
<path data-objid="0000X3"></path>
</g>
</svg>';
```

Same goes for attributes.
There you need to insert the attribute first, but you need to check with `[not(@data-objid)]` if the attribute already exists. Once it has been inserted where it's needed, you can modify the values.

```
SET @tXML.modify('insert attribute data-objid {"1"} into (//path[not(@data-objid) and contains("0000X1,0000X2", @data-objid) and string-length(@data-objid) != 0])[1]')
SET @tXML.modify('replace value of (//path[contains("0000X1,0000X2", @data-objid) and string-length(@data-objid) != 0]/@data-objid)[1] with "Test"')
```

Thus you created the attribute (with a dummy value) where the attribute didn't exist, and then you updated it where it already exists, which means all the values have been updated now, including the dummy values.

Since modify/insert can only operate on a single record, you **cannot** bulk-update/insert anyway. 
Interestingly, contrary to expectations, you **can** bulk delete... Not very consequent... I presume somebody ran out of time to implement this when shipping that crap.